# Which Doraemon episode was about a tree-seed thingy which became a girl?

Tags: doraemon

There is a tree-seed kind of a thing which Doraemon gets even though he did not buy it from the 22nd century. He tells Nobita not to use it, but he does and makes a girl. Now the girl is getting attached to Nobita and they don't know what to do. Finally, an old man sees her and realizes that she looks just like his dead daughter and so he adopts her.

Which episode was this?

Comment: Well, the name of the chapter depends heavily on the translation.

Comment: I just want some link so that i can read about that episode, some kind of identifying mark.

Comment: You should specify which iteration (1973, 1979, or 2005) of the Doraemon anime you're looking for. The 2011-ish reboot of the series made some changes to the plot and characters.

Answer (score 2):

These are the two I can find. The 1973 version did not adapt this story. Both are without subtitles though.

As for the summary you want, I was only able to find a Chinese version.

[Chinese Summary](http://zh.doraemon.wikia.com/wiki/%E7%AB%B9%E7%BE%8E%E4%BA%BA%E6%A9%9F%E5%99%A8%E4%BA%BA)

[1979 Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrimYoIH1iE) in Chinese

[2005 Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Y2iZsiRlCs) in Cantonese

Comment: Thanks to the Chinese summary, the episode is called "Kaguya Robot" on 1979 version ([Japanese version on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsYossdI-xU)). The 2005 version doesn't seem to be the same as described by OP though.

Comment: @AkiTanaka The 2005 version was a remake, it utilises the same items of Doraemon to tell a different story revolving the item, that is how the 2005 series works. OP watched the 1979 version, the 2005 version is a remake of that episode. I just included it for the sake of a more complete answer.

Comment: The 2 YouTube links are dead (as expected...)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding [Astral Sea's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/21656/2516), the story described in the question is about "Kaguya Robot", originally from manga volume 37 (under *Tentoumusi comics* label). The theme is based on "[The Tale of Princess Kaguya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Bamboo_Cutter)".

The 1979 version anime (episode 736) with the same title "[Kaguya Robot](https://www.bcdb.com/cartoon/168512-Kaguya-Robotto)" adapted the story faithfully. (*This is the one that's described in the question*)

The 2005 "renewal" version (episode 103B/195) titled "[Nobita Raises Princess Kaguya](http://doraemon.wikia.com/wiki/Nobita_Raises_Princess_Kaguya)" has a different story development while using the same "Princess Kaguya" theme.

Some of the differences are:

*Volume 37 "Kaguya Robot"*

> - The 22nd-century department store mistakenly delivered "Kaguya Robot"
>  - Doraemon hid it, but Nobita used it
>  - Nobita hid the newly-born Princess Kaguya from his mom and everyone
>  - Doraemon was very angry when he saw Kaguya Robot. Even though Nobita insisted to hide and raise her, Doraemon pointed his lack of plan cool-headedly
>  - When a wealthy person saw her daytime, he said "(she is) [as alike as two melons](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%93%9C%E4%BA%8C%E3%81%A4) as her late daughter. Please let her be adopted daughter."
>  - When Nobita bod farewell to Kaguya, he muttered: "A welcome from the moon came."

*Anime "Nobita Raises Princess Kaguya"*

> - The 22nd-century department store delivered a new product "Experience Folklore Set - Princess Kaguya Version"
>  - Nobita hid it from Doraemon and used the tool
>  - A newly-born Princess Kaguya befriended with Nobita's parents, his friends, and also Doraemon
>  - Princess Kaguya was making a sad face when she saw a full moon
>  - "Messenger from the moon" came and Nobita & co.'s repellance was in vain, then Princess Kaguya had to return
>  - When Princess Kaguya bod farewell, the letter she passed was the bill from the 22nd-century department store.

---

References:

- 1979 version episode number: [Doraemon Wikia](http://doraemon.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Doraemon_(1979_anime)_episodes#1983),
  [gouda1973's FC2 Blog (Japanese)](http://gouda1973.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-580.html)
- 2005 version episode number: [Doraemon Wikia](http://doraemon.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Doraemon_(2005_anime)_episodes#2007), [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%81%88%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A8%E3%83%94%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7_(2005%E5%B9%B44%E6%9C%88_-_)#2007.E5.B9.B4)
- The differences between each version: [Iseyan93's teacup Blog (Japanese)](http://star.ap.teacup.com/i-93/97.html)